How does one access the arguments of a function call when this function can not be rewritten due to its unknown implementation?
I have a function-returning function. The inner function makes use of the parent function's argument in its body. Then I make a list of functions produced by calling the parent function with different arguments. Here is an example:
function f(a) { return function(b) { return a * a + b; }; }
var fList = [f(-2), f(-1), f(0), f(1), f(2)];

Those are from a library and I cannot modify them.
I was wondering if there is any possibility to apply a filter on the fList based on the value of the argument of f. For example can I get the items in fList where the f function is called with a non-negative value? I tried inspecting fList[0] in debug console but could not make any progress unfortunately.
I feel like this is not possible. However, since when I call fList[0](2) it uses the a variable's value of -2, I am hoping so.
Please do not suggest using an inverse function, that's why I made it return the square of the searched argument plus the inner one. Above is an over-simplified example and the body in the real case is much different with some side effects.

guess they are private and cannot be accessed from outside

The returned function closes over the variable a and thus is available only to that functions scope. You can not get direct access to the variable a because it is a copy of the argument passed. You could do this f = obj => b => obj.a * obj.a + b; a1 = {a:-2}; fList = [f(a1), ... where the object a1 has the value a1.a

@cmgchess looks to be so. Blindman67, I guess it is the same as Alexander's answer below. Please see my comment to that answer. Thank you both for chipping in!

Do you mean fList is from a library?

@xuhdev That's right. I just want to inspect the internals of a lambda function that I can call but not change.

@burkay ... 1/2 ... since you can call the function you obviously know its name an can access it. Modifying functions takes place right after the environment/modules is/are loaded. One just passes the to be modified function into the modifier and does reassign the modifiers result to the functions identifier ... f = (function (proceed) { return function (...args) { const result = proceed(...args); Reflect.defineProperty(result, 'args', { value: args }); return result; }; }(f)); ... It's really as simple as that; its a straightforward approach with no magic behind it.

@burkay ... 2/2 ... Whoever or whatever process uses f next does already deal with the modified version of f which behaves exactly like before and therefore does not break any other code. The modified function's return value (a function itself) just features an additional (non enumerable, non writable) args property upon which the OP can build his very use case specific logic.

@Peter thank you very much for the detailed answer and your comments. I upvoted your post. But since it is still a workaround, I will not mark it as the answer.

if your fList is in numerical order (as you show above), then you know that every element in fList before the result of 0 (ie f(0) = 0 * 0 + 0 = 0) is from a negative number

Unfortunately, it was just an simplified example. Anyway, thank you for the effort!

If you can override f:


function f(a) { return function(b) { return a * a + b; }; }

const param = Symbol();
// override f() and assign the param to it
f = a => {
  const out = b => a * a + b;
  out[param] = a;
  return out;
};

var fList = [f(-2), f(-1), f(0), f(1), f(2)];

const positive = fList.filter(f => f[param] >= 0);

console.log(positive.map(f=>f(3)));




I guess that is not a direct solution but a good workaround. However, I do not want to touch the library functions. If I have to, it would be better to override the parent's caller function in the first place. Anyway, thank you for the suggestion!

Since the original library function is of unknown implementation it therefore can not be directly rewritten/reimplemented and enhanced.
The OP's task is to capture the a parameter value of a function f neither knowing the implementation of f nor actually touching f itself.
Such a scenario can only be solved by function- or method-modification based on a function wrapping approach.
With the next provided solution the OP can choose to either reassign the ad hoc created modified version of the original function to this very function's variable name (or namespace) or to assign it to another constant/variable. Either way, the modified function will always feature the original function's name since the name might be of importance for some use cases. In addition, in order to be even more generic, the wrapper does not just assign the passed parameter to the returned function, but does assign all passed arguments as an array.
Edit targeting following of the OP's comments ...

... That's right. I just want to inspect the internals of a lambda function that I can call but not change. – burkay

@burkay ... 1/2 ... since you can call the function you obviously know its name and can access it. Modifying functions takes place right after the environment/modules is/are loaded. One just passes the to be modified function into the modifier and does reassign the modifiers result to the functions identifier ...
f = (function (proceed) {
  return function (...args) {
    const result = proceed(...args);
    Reflect.defineProperty(result, 'args', { value: args });
    return result;
  };
}(f));

... It's really as simple as that; its a straightforward approach with no magic behind it. – Peter Seliger
@burkay ... 2/2 ... Whoever or whatever process uses f next does already deal with the modified version of f which behaves exactly like before and therefore does not break any other code. The modified function's return value (a function itself) just features an additional (non enumerable, non writable) args property upon which the OP can build his very use case specific logic. – Peter Seliger




// - original library function of unknown
//   implementation which therefore can not
//   be directly rewritten and enhanced.

function f(a) {
  return function (b) {
    return a * a + b;
  };
}

// - the task is to capture the `a` parameter value of function `f`.

// - thus, one has to rely on method-modification,
//   based on a function wrapping approach.

// - ad hoc creation and re/assignment of the function's modified version.
f = (function (proceed) {

  return ({
    // preserve the original function's name.
    [proceed.name]: function (...args) {

      const result = proceed(...args);

      if (typeof result === 'function') {

        // - assign the entire `arguments` as array to the
        //   to be returned function's `args` property.
        Reflect
          .defineProperty(result, 'args', { value: args });
      }
      return result;
    }
  })[proceed.name];

}(f)); // provide the original function of unknown implementation.

const fList = [f(-2), f(-1), f(0), f(1), f(2)];
const nonNegativeParameterFList = fList.filter(f => f.args.at(0) >= 0);

console.log(
  nonNegativeParameterFList.map(f => f(3))
);
console.log(
  nonNegativeParameterFList.map(f => f.args)
);
console.log('f.name ...', f.name);
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }




I guess this is a complicated version of @Alexander Nenashev's approach. Thank you for the effort but this is not what I asked for.

@burkay ... 1/2 ... nope, you guessed wrong. My answer offers an approach which only needs to "know" that there is a function which creates and returns another function, and that one somehow needs to access the creator function's argument/s at its call time. The entire solution is agnostic to the implementation details of both functions (creating and created one), whereas with Alexander's approach one needs to know the implementation details of the created function. The only thing both solutions have in common is that the returned function does carry the creator function's argument/s.

@burkay ... 2/2 ... In other words Alexander's solution works exactly for the given example whereas my solution works for any of your library functions that follow the pattern of being creators of other functions. Maybe the OP thinks about providing more details or additional code examples about the real scenario which the OP is confronted with.

Checked your code more carefully after reading your comment. Your answer is useful for sure and I upvoted it. However, I still think it is a workaround, not actually inspecting the internals of the original function, which I asked for in the first place (I am the OP). I will keep this question open, in case it becomes solvable in the future.

@burkay ... The function wrapping based method-modifier approach actually is as far as one will ever get unless one is going to lay hands on the source code itself by an additional transpiler/preprocessor task where one does parse and change this very code. Method modification gives one insights into the control flow and the power to change the latter. One can intercept function calls including the arguments which is a powerful introspection feature, one can read and manipulate return values, one e.g. could apply/implement logging and exception handling within/into functions one does not own.

I see that. Thank you for taking the time to give such detailed information.
